# Spring based client server communication without network

Tags: java, spring, sockets

I have to write two(you can name it as client and server) spring based application/program where both app will run on same JVM and communicate with each other(send some text based message). these are few constrain i have to keep in mind -

one: application should run in non-networked mode(no network communication)not even any loopback address.

two: also i can't use serialization :(

is there a way we can achieve this using Spring framework, without using JMS, RMI( i believe RMI also use networking). any expert input from your side is highly appreciated. many thanks in advance.

ps: data which is part of communication is text(String).

Comment: could i use java in memory mapped file in this scenario?